# code only take 2 inputs although it has 3 fgets

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, fgets

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);  // The input is 3 so i use it to simplify the question 
    char array[num][1000];
    fgets(array[0],1000,stdin);
    fgets(array[1],1000,stdin);
    fgets(array[2],1000,stdin);
    printf("%s %s %s",array[0],array[1],array[2]);
}
```

The first input i.e. for scanf is 3 then i input mahatma and the gandhi. Now it should ask for another input for the last fgets but the programme ends printing mahatma gandhi. I however i do not use scanf then the result is correct. If possible please provide a code.
P.S- I am using fgets for the 1st time so there may be a very basic mistake.

Comment: @xing i suspected the sameas printf was printing a \n. how can i correct it

Comment: @xing can you provide a code for that please

Answer (score 2):

The reason, as xing noted in comments, is that `scanf()` leaves a newline in the stream (represented by the file handle `stdin`) that will be read by the first call of `fgets()`, causing it to return immediately.

The general solution is not to mix formatted input (like `scanf()`) with line oriented input (like `fgets()`) on the same input stream, since they will interact in unexpected ways.  Your example here (`scanf()` leaving a newline to be read, and `fgets()` returning immediately due to encountering the newline) is one of many possible consequences of mixing styles of input on the same stream.

One way is to use `fgets()` to read data to a string, and then read an `int` from that string using `sscanf()`.    The interaction with `stdin` then ONLY uses `fgets()`.

Another option would be to change all the usages of `fgets()` to use `scanf()`.   This will require finding a sensible format (bearing in mind that `scanf()` stops reading something when it encounters whitespace - although there are some format specifiers that change this).

The advice of adding a space to the `scanf()` format string is flawed.  It works for specific cases (like this one), but not for others.   For example, if you do a loop of the form

```
// assume variables declared as in the OP's question

while (some_condition_that_is_true_more_than_once())
{
    scanf("%d ",&num);
    fgets(array[0],1000,stdin);
    fgets(array[1],1000,stdin);
    fgets(array[2],1000,stdin);
}
```

there will still be a potential interaction (depending on what the user inputs) that gives unexpected results due to interaction of the last call of `fgets()` in the loop with the `scanf()` call in the next iteration.

Comment: O_O This is how you become LEGEND _/\_

Comment: @peter how can i print all the names get by fgets in one line as fgets also stores \n and hence using printf all are printed on new lines. how can i remove the \n

Comment: Look for a newline in the string, using a loop.   Overwrite it with something.   If the string read by `fgets()` has a newline, it will be at the end (immediately before the trailing zero).    Bear in mind that `fgets()` might stop before it reads a newline, and therefore not place it in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using fgets for all input. Parse as needed with sscanf or others.
Check the return of fgets and sscanf as that will indicate problems.
The do/while loop will continue until a positive integer is processed.
Include prompts to clarify the expected inputs.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char input[50] = "";
    int num = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int valid = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "enter an integer\n");
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            if ( 1 != ( valid = sscanf ( input, "%d", &num))) {// 1 means successful scan on an integer
                valid = 0;
                printf ( "try again to enter an integer\n");
            }
        }
        else {// fgets could not get input
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem with input\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( !valid || num < 0);

    char array[num][1000];

    for ( loop = 0; loop < num; loop++) {
        printf ( "enter text for array[%d]\n", loop);
        if ( fgets(array[loop],sizeof array[loop], stdin)) {
            array[loop][strcspn( array[loop], "\n")] = '\0';// remove trailing newline if any
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem with input\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for ( loop = 0; loop < num; loop++) {
        printf("%s ", array[loop]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a space in `scanf()`like this

`scanf("%d ",&num);`

this will make calling `fgets` three times(Just for this case as pointed by Peter). This is happening because when you press ENTER key after `scanf()` in `STDIN` buffer `\n` is stored and that gets into first `fgets()` call.

Comment: thanks yaar, such an eloquent solution. how can i print all the names get by fgets in one line as fgets also stores \n and hence using printf all are printed on new lines.

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&num);` will consume not only a single following `'\n'`, but all following white-spaces.  This is not useful if the first of the 3 following lines begins with white-space.